# Grails Application upgradation from 2.2.1 To 3.1.1 java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: grails, nullpointerexception

I am doing up gradation of project from grails 2.2.1 to grails 3.1.1. I followed the step given at grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html. Getting this error when i run the cmd -grails compile. How to solve the above error.

> | Error Command [null] error: null (NOTE: Stack trace has been
>   filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   org.grails.build.parsing.ScriptNameResolver.resolvesTo(ScriptNameResolver.groovy:34)
>   at
>   org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile$_handleCommand_closure9.doCall(AbstractProfile.groovy:431)
>   at
>   org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.handleCommand(AbstractProfile.groovy:430)
>   at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:362) at
>   org.grails.cli.GrailsCli$_handleCommandWithCancellationSupport_closure6.doCall(GrailsCli.groovy:457)
>   at
>   org.grails.cli.GrailsCli$_handleCommandWithCancellationSupport_closure6.call(GrailsCli.groovy)
>   | Error Command [null] error: null

Comment: What is your question?When did you encountered this problem?

Comment: I am doing up gradation of project from grails 2.2.1 to grails 3.1.1.
I followed the step given at https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html. 
Getting this error when i run the cmd -grails compile.
How to solve the above error.

Comment: ow..i never seen this...

Comment: You should be using https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.1.x/guide/upgrading.html (not 3.0.x). I'd also suggest upgrading to intermediate versions if that fails. E.g. 2.2 -> 2.3.x-> 2.4.x -> 2.5.x -> 3.0 -> 3.1. Its a PIA but sometime the only way in my experience.

Comment: What is the current version of grails in your project? Look in either 'application.properties' (grails 2.x) or 'gradle.properties' (grails 3.x). Then make sure the version of grails you are using matches the one you found.